# Sqlite3: Advanced SELECT Query

Tags: sqlite

I am DB development noob and I am having troubles in writing nested SELECT queries. I will try to explain the scenario.

I have three tables and I would like to get an ATTRIBUTE-1 from TABLE 1 with WHERE conditions and get an ATTRIBUTE-2 from TABLE 2 with WHERE conditions using ATTRIBUTE-1 and finally get an ATTRIBUTE-3 from TABLE 3 with WHERE conditions using ATTRIBUTE-2.

Please excuse my explanation cause I have no idea how these explanantions are made in DB domain.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `ATTRIBUTE-1`? I understood that  if `ATTRIBUTE = 5` then you wanna get `4`?

Comment: @JorgeRibeiro I meant ATTRIBUTE-1 as an item in a column from a specific row of a table. SELECT ATTRIBUTE -1 FROM TABLE-1 WHERE ATTRIBUTE-2 = "SOMETHING";

Comment: An example usually helps readers understand the question. Some little tables with some values and your desired query output.

Answer (score 0):

Given these example tables and values:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Attribute1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (10), (15), (20);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Attribute2);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (11), (16), (21);

CREATE TABLE Table3 (Attribute3);
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES (12), (17), (22);
```

Here's a simple query you could do:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Attribute1 AS Ret1,
    Table2.Attribute2 AS Ret2,
    Table3.Attribute3 AS Ret3
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 JOIN Table3
WHERE Ret1 >= 10 AND Ret1 <= 15
AND Ret2 = Ret1 + 1
AND Ret3 = Ret2 + 1
```

This returns:

```
Ret1 Ret2 Ret3
10   11   12
15   16   17
```

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, it's probably too vague and you should try with a new, more specific question. The thing I both like (and dislike) about SQL is that it's built around lots of specific solutions to specific problems. It's good because many common use-cases are cleanly covered, but bad because it's not always obvious how to build a solution to a problem that isn't covered.